# How to incress footer height in pdfmake

Tags: typescript, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake and I would like to incress the height of the footer of my pdf.

I have this code for the footer so far

```
  footer: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
    return {
      height: 40,
      table: {
        widths: ['*', 100],
        body: [
          [
            { text: 'some information', alignment: 'center', fontSize: 9, },
          ],
          [
            { text: 'some more information', alignment: 'center', fontSize: 9, },
          ],
          [
            { text: 'and even more information', alignment: 'center', fontSize: 9, },
          ],
          [
            [{ text: 'Page ' + pageCount, alignment: 'right', margin: [5], fontSize: 5, }]
          ]
        ]
      },
      layout: 'noBorders'
    };
  },
```

I have added a height property that I have set to 40 when I set it to a heigher number for example 80 it has no effect on the height of the footer how can I fix this issue tank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve my problem thanks to you. I have answerd my question in case someone comes across the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to have a larger footer by change the page margins by addeding this line

```
  pageMargins: [40, 80, 40, 60],
```

like so under my document definition

```
let docDefinition = {
  pageSize: 'LEGAL',
  pageMargins: [40, 80, 40, 60],
}
```

Comment: Just something to note, the margins do not include the footer, so when setting these, you should leave a big enough margin for your entire footer plus the margin underneath it. i.e. If you wanted an image in the footer 100 high, and a 50 gap under it, then set bottom margin to 150.